# If clients to a node.js application all share the same event queue, how does node.js keep track of which context events belong to?

Tags: node.js

Here is an example to illustrate what I am talking about:

```
var BlueBirdPromise = require('bluebird');

function getFriendsList(user_id) {

//return Promise to a list of this user's friends that gets fulfilled after doing some io with a database

};

function getFriendRequestsList(user_id){

//return Promise to a list of this user's friend requests that gets fulfilled after doing some io with a database  

};

router.get('/homepage', function (req, res) {

    BlueBirdPromise.coroutine(function* () {

        var lists = yield BlueBirdPromise.props({

            friends_list: getFriendsList(req.user_id),
            friend_requests_lists: getFriendRequestsList(req.user_id)

        });

        return lists;

    })()
        .then(function (lists) {

            res.render('homepage', {

                lists: lists

            });

        })
        .catch(function (error) {

            console.log(error);

            res.render('homepage', {

                lists: { friends_list: [], friend_requests_list: [] }

            });

        });



});
```

Say that the events happen in the following order:

At time t = 1, ClientA requests the index resource and this request is placed on the event queue.

At time t = 2, ClientB requests the index resource and this request is placed on the event queue.

At time t = 3, the event loop runs

At time t = 4, the io for ClientA's friends list is sent off to the database.

At time t = 5, the io for ClientA's friend requests lists is sent off to the database.

At time t = 6, the io for ClientB's friends list is sent off to the database.

At time t = 7, the io for ClientB's friend requests lists is sent off to the database.

At time t = 8, the io for ClientA's friends list is ready and is placed on the event queue.

At time t = 9, the io for ClientB's friends list is ready and is placed on the event queue.

At time t = 10, the io for ClientB's friend requests list is ready and is placed on the event queue.

At time t = 11, the io for ClientA's friend requests list is ready and is place on the event queue.

At time t = 12, the event queue from front to back looks like this:

ClientA FriendsList Ready Event -> ClientB FriendRequestsList Ready Event -> ClientB FriendsList Ready Event -> ClientA FriendRequestsList Ready Event

At time t = 13, the event loop runs the front event.

At time t = 14, the friends_list gets set with ClientA's friends.

At time t = 16, the event loop runs the next front event.

At time t = 16, the friend_requests_list gets set with ClientB's friend requests.

My question in this example is, at this point how does node know not to return to ClientA, ClientA's friends list with
ClientB's friend requests list?

Even at time t = 6 and 7, how do those requests not overwrite the requests at time t = 4 and 5?

I guess I am having trouble wrapping my head around how there are no lightweight processes anywhere under the hood to create 
seperate stacks.